# Can't fetch the title from a problematic webpage using requests implementing proxies within

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to fetch the title from a [webpage](https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate). The title visible in there as `BM Wendling Real Estate`. The script that I've tried with sometimes can scrape it accordingly but most of the time throws 403 status. As the site bans ips, I used proxies to bypass that.

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"}

def get_proxy_list():
    r = requests.get('https://www.sslproxies.org/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    proxies = [':'.join([item.select_one("td").text,item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text]) for item in soup.select("table.table tr") if "yes" in item.text]
    return proxies

def get(proxies):
    proxy = proxies.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies)))
    return {'https': f'http://{proxy}','http': f'http://{proxy}'}

def scrape(url,proxy,proxies):
    while True:
        try:
            print("proxy being used: {}".format(proxy))
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
            assert r.status_code == 200
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
            title = soup.select_one(".bizname_hdr > h1").get_text(strip=True)
            return title
        except Exception as e:
            proxy = get(proxies)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proxies = get_proxy_list()
    proxy = get(proxies)
    
    title = scrape(link,proxy,proxies)
    print(title)
```

Question: `How can I scrape the title unhindered?`

Note: The site restricts it's access to few countries.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, why do you want to fetch the title from individual business pages? Is there something else you're actually trying to do page by page? I ask because some of the site's other pages seem to load much faster, and there may be a workaround depending on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Matt L., It's not only the title I'm after. There are few other information that I would like to parse from those individual pages as they are not available elsewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a long story, but one with a semi-happy ending, so please bear with me:

First, I made a a few change to your program. The first one was to ensure that I was only selecting proxies where 'yes' was in the 'Https' column. Second, I think the `requests` documentation may have been a bit misleading. The `proxies` header has two keys, 'https' and 'http', but I am sure that these should be different IP/Port combinations. Since the proxies we are using are HTTPS proxies, I am only providing the 'https' key. Finally, I have changed the function interfaces slightly and printed out some diagnostics:

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate'
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"}

def get_proxy_list():
    r = requests.get('https://www.sslproxies.org/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
    proxies = (
        ((item.select_one("td").text, item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(2)").text), item.select_one("td:nth-of-type(7)").text)
        for item in soup.select("table.table tr") if "yes" in item.text
    )
    proxies = filter(lambda proxy: proxy[1] == 'yes', proxies)
    return [':'.join(proxy[0]) for proxy in proxies]


def select_proxy(proxies):
    proxy = proxies.pop(random.randrange(len(proxies)))
    #return {'https': f'https://{proxy}','http': f'http://{proxy}'}
    return {'https': f'http://{proxy}'}


def scrape(url):
    proxies = get_proxy_list()
    while True:
        try:
            proxy = select_proxy(proxies)
            print("\nproxy being used: {}".format(proxy))
            r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=10)
            assert r.status_code == 200
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
            xpath = '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1'
            title = soup.select_one(".bizname_hdr > h1").get_text(strip=True)
            return title
        except Exception as e:
            print('Exception is:', e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    title = scrape(link)
    print(title)
```

What I got was a lot of errors:

```
proxy being used: {'https': 'http://71.19.145.97:6100'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027DCFBB35E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://1.20.100.134:40698'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027DCFBB3DF0>, 'Connection to 1.20.100.134 timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://212.126.102.142:31785'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out')))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://68.183.185.149:8118'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027DCFBB38E0>, 'Connection to 68.183.185.149 timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://141.0.11.243:80'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error')))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://139.59.90.141:80'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out')))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://36.89.8.235:8080'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000027DCFBC24F0>, 'Connection to 36.89.8.235 timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://150.242.182.98:80'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('timed out')))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://168.169.146.12:8080'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))

etc.
```

I broke out of the above. I noticed that when I entered the link URL in my Chrome browser that it took an extremely long time for the host name to be resolved. But when I reload the page it just takes a very long time for the page to reload. I am guessing that perhaps that some of the above timeouts are due to proxies having the same difficulty. There are, of course, errors just trying to connect to the proxy itself. But all of this may be moot. Now that I have connected to the website, I am able to fetch the page simply with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import time

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.183 Safari/537.36"}
url = 'https://www.veteranownedbusiness.com/business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate'
t0 = time()
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=120)
text = r.text
t1 = time()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
title = soup.select_one(".bizname_hdr > h1").get_text(strip=True)
print(title, t1 - t0)
```

Prints:

```
BM Wendling Real Estate 63.243138551712036
```

Note that I specified a 120 second timeout. And in fact it took 63 seconds for the results to come back. Yet when I ping the host, it comes back rather quickly:

```
Pinging www.veteranownedbusiness.com [172.67.75.109] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.67.75.109: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=59
Reply from 172.67.75.109: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=59
Reply from 172.67.75.109: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=59
Reply from 172.67.75.109: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=59

Ping statistics for 172.67.75.109:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 3ms
```

So the hang up is probably not so much slow DNS lookup in general but whatever it is that causes the long time it takes for the page to load.

So I went back to the original program (actually my updated version) and changed the timeout value to 120. I am not sure if this gives more time to connect to the proxy but it seems to give more time to connect to the actual website. The results were:

```
proxy being used: {'https': 'http://217.172.122.5:8080'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002DF162D3460>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://36.89.182.225:32338'}
Exception is: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.veteranownedbusiness.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /business/25150/bm-wendling-real-estate (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002DF162D3C70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))

proxy being used: {'https': 'http://95.58.145.22:8080'}
BM Wendling Real Estate
```

I was lucky to get a result on the third proxy try. I have rerun this several times since and after approximately 10 - 15 unsuccessful tries I break out. I have only have had one further success.

Comment: It seems you are very right with the issue that you have addressed. I would never think of going beyond 60 seconds for the timeout value. The script appears to be working correctly now. Thanks.

Comment: When I tried yesterday, your suggested approach (increasing the value of timeout) worked out. However, when I tried today, it didn't work at all even after 100 retries.

Comment: Try loading the URLs in your browser and you will see that the page-load time is incredibly long (it just took me 70 seconds, but I believe at times it might take more than 120 seconds). I just ran my code now (without using proxies) and so it worked because 70 < 120. But I have no control over their page-load times. You should contact their help desk and find out why their response is so poor.